# Function with $f(x)f(y)=f(xy)$ satisfying intermediate value property

Tags: real-analysis, functions

Find all functions $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ such that $f(xy)=f(x)f(y)$ for all $x,y\in\mathbb{R}$, and $f$ satisfies the intermediate value property.

Taking $x=0$, we have $f(0)=f(x)f(0)$. If $f(0)\neq 0$, then $f(x)=1$ for all $x$, which is a solution. Else, $f(0)=0$. Another solution is $f(x)=0$ for all $x$. We have $f(x^2)=f(x)^2$, which means that $f(x)\geq 0$ for $x\geq 0$. It's not clear how to use the intermediate value property.

Comment: Another class of solutions is $f(x) = |x|^p$ for any positive exponent $p$, and I assume your goal is to show that these are basically all solutions, possibly with a negative sign for negative $x$.

Answer (score 3):

Let $\mathscr{F}$ be the set of functions $f:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$ that satisfy $f(xy)=f(x)f(y)$ for all $x,y\in\Bbb R$, and let $\mathscr{F}_0=\{f\in\mathscr{F}:f\text{ is Darboux}\}$. It’s possible to describe explicitly all *continuous* members of $\mathscr{F}_0$, which are in fact also the Lebesgue measurable members of $\mathscr{F}_0$, but assuming the axiom of choice it is not possible to give explicit descriptions of *all* members of $\mathscr{F}_0$.

The continuous members are precisely the functions mentioned in the question and the comment by Lukas Geyer. Suppose that $f\in\mathscr{F}$; then for $x\ge 0$ we must have $f(x)=\left(f\left(x^{1/2}\right)\right)^2\ge 0$. Moreover, if $x\in\{0,1\}$, then $x^2=x$, so $f(x)=f(x^2)=\big(f(x)\big)^2$, and $f(x)\in\{0,1\}$.

- If $f(1)=0$, then $f(x)=f(1\cdot x)=f(1)f(x)=0$ for all $x\in\Bbb R$.
- If $f(0)=1$, then $f(x)=f(0)f(x)=f(0\cdot x)=f(0)=1$ for all $x\in\Bbb R$.

Both of these constant functions are of course Darboux.

The only remaining possibility is that $f(0)=0$ and $f(1)=1$, which we now assume. Let $x\in\Bbb R$; an easy induction shows that $f(x^n)=\big(f(x)\big)^n$ for all $n\in\Bbb Z^+$. Thus if $x>0$, then $\big(f\left(x^{1/n}\right)\big)^n=f(x)$ for $n\in\Bbb Z^+$, and hence $f\left(x^{1/n}\right)=\big(f(x)\big)^{1/n}$. More generally, if $x>0$ and $m,n\in\Bbb Z^+$, then

$$f\left(x^{m/n}\right)=f\left(x^{1/n}\right)^m=\big(f(x)\big)^{m/n}\,,$$

i.e., $f(x^q)=\big(f(x)\big)^q$ for all $q\in\Bbb Q^+$.

It’s also clear that for $x\in\Bbb R\setminus\{0\}$ we have $f\left(\frac1x\right)=\frac1{f(x)}$, since $f(x)f\left(\frac1x\right)=f(1)=1$. Thus, $f(x)>0$ for $x>0$, and if in addtion $q\in\Bbb Q^+$, then

$$f(x^{-q})=f\left(\frac1{x^q}\right)=f\left(\left(\frac1x\right)^q\right)=\left(f\left(\frac1x\right)\right)^q=\left(\frac1{f(x)}\right)^q=\big(f(x)\big)^{-q}\,,$$

so $f(x^q)=\big(f(x)\big)^q$ for all $x\in\Bbb R^+$ and $q\in\Bbb Q$.

We are still assuming that $f(0)=0$, so if $f(x)=1$ for every $x\in\Bbb R^+$, $f$ is clearly not Darboux. Thus, we may as well assume that there is an $a\in\Bbb R^+$ such that $f(a)\ne 1$; let $c=f(a)>0$. There is an $r\in\Bbb R$ such that $c=a^r$, so that $f(a^q)=c^q=a^{rq}$ for all $q\in\Bbb Q$. The continuous functions are Darboux, and $r\Bbb Q$ is dense in $\Bbb R$, so we should definitely look at functions $f$ for which there is an $\alpha\in\Bbb R$ such that $f(x)=x^\alpha$ for all $x\in\Bbb R^+$. If $\alpha<0$, such a function is not Darboux on any interval $[0,a]$ with $a>0$, so we may as well assume that $\alpha>0$. ($0^0=1\ne 0=f(0)$, so $\alpha\ne 0$.) Whether $x^\alpha$ is defined for negative $x$ depends on $\alpha$, but $|x|^\alpha$ is defined for all $x\in\Bbb R$, and it is straightforward to verify that for each $\alpha>0$ the function $f_\alpha^+(x)=|x|^\alpha$ is a continuous member of $\mathscr{F}$ and hence belongs to $\mathscr{F}_0$.

Suppose that $\alpha>0$, and $f(x)=x^\alpha$ for all $x\in\Bbb R^+$. $\big(f(-1)\big)^2=1$, so $f(-1)\in\{1,-1\}$, and $f(x)=f(-1)f(|x|)=f(-1)|x|^\alpha$ for each $x\in\Bbb R^-$. Thus, either $f(-1)=1$ and $f=f_\alpha^+$, or $f(-1)=-1$ and $f$ is the function

$$f_\alpha^-(x)=\begin{cases}
-|x|^\alpha,&\text{if }x<0\\
x^\alpha,&\text{if }x\ge 0\,,
\end{cases}$$

which is also a continuous member of $\mathscr{F}$ and hence in $\mathscr{F}_0$.

In fact the functions $f_\alpha^+$ and $f_\alpha^-$ for $\alpha>0$ and the constant functions $f(x)\equiv 0$ and $f(x)\equiv 1$ are the only continuous members of $\mathscr{F}_0$. To prove this, suppose that $f\in\mathscr{F}_0$ is continuous and not identically zero, and define

$$g:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R:x\mapsto\ln f(e^x)\,.$$

Then for all $x,y\in\Bbb R$ we have

$$g(x+y)=\ln f(e^{x+y})=\ln f(e^xe^y)=\ln\big(f(e^x)f(e^y)\big)=\ln f(e^x)+\ln f(e^y)=g(x)+g(y)\,,$$

i.e., $g$ satisfies the [Cauchy functional equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_functional_equation). It is well known that all continuous solutions $h$ of this functional equation are of the form $h(y)=yh(1)$, and $g$ is continuous, so

$$y\ln f(e)=yg(1)=g(y)=\ln f(e^y)$$

for all $y\in\Bbb R$. In particular, if $x\in\Bbb R^+$ and $y=\ln x$, then

$$\ln f(x)=\ln f(e^y)=\ln x\ln f(e)=\ln x^{\ln f(e)}\,,$$

so $f(x)=x^{\ln f(e)}$ for all $x\in\Bbb R^+$, i.e., $f$ is either $f_{\ln f(e)}^+$, $f_{\ln f(e)}^-$, or identically $1$.

In fact in 1920 Banach and Sierpiński showed, independently and using different methods, that all Lebesgue measurable solutions of it are of this form, so these are also the only Lebesgue measurable functions in $\mathscr{F}_0$. All of these results on the Cauchy functional equation can be found in Kaushal Verma, [A Primer on the Functional Equation $f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y)$](https://www.ias.ac.in/article/fulltext/reso/022/10/0935-0941) [PDF].

However, the axiom of choice implies that $\mathscr{F}_0$ contains other functions as well. To show this, we start with any Hamel basis $B'=\{b_\xi':\xi<2^\omega\}$ for $\Bbb R$ over $\Bbb Q$. Let $\mathscr{B}=\{V_n:n\in\omega\}$ be a countable base for the usual topology on $\Bbb R$, and enumerate $\mathscr{B}\times 2^\omega$ as $\{\langle V_{n_\xi},\alpha_\xi\rangle:\xi<2^\omega\}$.

For $\xi<2^\omega$ we recursively choose $q_\xi\in\Bbb Q$ so that $q_\xi b_\xi'\in V_{n_\xi}$, and the points $q_\xi b_\xi'$ are all distinct.

> Suppose that $\eta<2^\omega$, and for each $\xi<\eta$ we have chosen $q_\xi\in\Bbb Q$ so that $q_\xi b_\xi'\in V_{n_\xi}$. $\Bbb Qb_\eta$ is dense in $\Bbb R$, so there is a $q_\eta\in\Bbb Q$ such that $q_\eta b_\eta'\in V_{n_\eta}$. Moreover, $\Bbb Q b_\eta\cap\{q_\xi b_\xi':\xi<\eta\}=\varnothing$, since $B$ is linearly independent over $\Bbb Q$.

For $\xi<2^\omega$ let $b_\xi=q_\xi b_\xi'$ and $a_\xi=e^{b_\xi}$, and let $B=\{b_\xi:\xi<2^\omega\}$; note that $B$ is a Hamel base for $\Bbb R$ over $\Bbb Q$. Finally, enumerate $\Bbb R^+$ as $\{y_\xi:\xi<2^\omega\}$, and for $\xi<2^\omega$ let $c_\xi=y_{\alpha_\xi}$.

Let $x\in\Bbb R^+\setminus\{1\}$; then $\ln x\ne 0$, so there are a finite $F\subseteq 2^\omega$ and non-zero rationals $p_\xi$ for $\xi\in F$ such that $\ln x=\sum_{\xi\in F}p_\xi b_\xi$, and hence

$$x=e^{\sum_{\xi\in F}p_\xi b_\xi}=\prod_{\xi\in F}e^{p_\xi b_\xi}=\prod_{\xi\in F}a_\xi^{p_\xi}\,,$$

and we set $f(-x)=\varphi(x)=\prod_{\xi\in F}c_\xi^{p_\xi}$. To complete the definition of $f:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$, set $f(-1)=f(1)=1$ and $\varphi(0)=0$. It is now straightforward to check that $f(xy)=f(x)f(y)$ for all $x,y\in\Bbb R$, so that $f\in\mathscr{F}$.

Now let $U$ be any non-empty open subset of $\Bbb R^+$. Then $\ln[U]=\{\ln y:y\in U\}$ is an open subset of $\Bbb R$, and there is an $n\in\omega$ such that $V_n\subseteq\ln[U]$. Let $y\in\Bbb R$ be arbitrary; there is an $\eta<2^\omega$ such that $y_\eta=y$, and there is a $\xi<2^\omega$ such that $n_\xi=n$ and $\alpha_\xi=\eta$. Then $b_\xi\in V_n\subseteq\ln[U]$, so $a_\xi=e^{b_\xi}\in U$, and $f(a_\xi)=c_\xi=y_{\alpha_\xi}=y_\eta=y$.
Thus, $f[U]\supseteq\Bbb R^+$, and $f$ is a Darboux function that is nowhere continuous.